# Error 405 Only POST allowed throw when use SOAP api in Experience Cloud

Tags: soap-api, experience-cloud

I use SOAP api to get RecordType's information in my VF Page. When I use this VF Page in Experience Cloud with Partner user it will throw "Error 405 Only POST allowed".

Error Message as follow:

```
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html;charset=utf-8"/>
<title>Error 405 Only POST allowed</title>
</head>
<body><h2>HTTP ERROR 405</h2>
<p>Problem accessing /services/Soap/u/40.0. Reason:
<pre>Only POST allowed</pre></p><hr /><br/>
<!-- Body events -->
<script type="text/javascript">function bodyOnLoad(){if(window.PreferenceBits){window.PreferenceBits.prototype.csrfToken="null";};}function bodyOnBeforeUnload(){}function bodyOnFocus(){}function bodyOnUnload(){}</script>
</body>
</html>
```

I try debug this error and I found it's in Salesforce's "connection.js" file.

[image]

"envelope" value as follow:

```
<se:Envelope xmlns:se=\"http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/\">
<se:Header xmlns:sfns=\"urn:partner.soap.sforce.com\">
<sfns:SessionHeader>
<sessionId><--!My SessionId--></sessionId>
</sfns:SessionHeader>
<sfns:CallOptions>
<client><--!My Client--></client>
</sfns:CallOptions>
</se:Header>
<se:Body>
<describeLayout xmlns=\"urn:partner.soap.sforce.com\" xmlns:ns1=\"sobject.partner.soap.sforce.com\">
<sObjectType>Account</sObjectType>
<layoutName xmlns:xsi=\"http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance\" xsi:nill=\"true\"/>
<recordTypeIds>0125f000000tguIAAQ</recordTypeIds>
<recordTypeIds>0125f000000tgu8AAA</recordTypeIds>
</describeLayout>
</se:Body>
</se:Envelope>
```

Since Winter 19 I use SOAP api to get RecordType information, and as far as I know, this error never been meet before. I think maybe current Salesforce's update cause this issue.

Another found about this issue is SOAP api works fine when in Visualforce + Tabs type Experience.

Do you have any fix idea about this issue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason is server url not correct in this case. Please add community prefixPath before server url.